# Can I link Django permissions to a model class instead of User instances?

Tags: python, django, database-design

I know how permissions/groups/user work together in a "normal" way.
However, I feel incomfortable with this way to do in my case, let me explain why.

In my Django models, all my users are extended with models like "Landlord" or "Tenant".

Every landlord will have the same permissions, every tenant will have other same permissions.. So it seems to me there is not interest to handle permission in a "user per user" way.

What I'd like to do is link the my Tenant and Landlord models (not the instances) to lists of permissions (or groups).

Is there a way to do this? Am I missing something in my modelisation? How would you do that?

Comment: Can't you use permission groups for this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization

Answer (score 1):

`django.contrib.auth` has groups and group permissions, so all you have to do is to define `landlords` and `tenants` groups with the appropriate permissions then on your models's `save()` method (or using signals or else) add your `Landlord` and `Tenant` instances to their respective groups.

Comment: Yes I could do that, but eventually in the database, groups/permission are handled user per user (each user has a relation to groups/permission). This means, at a database level, 2 users of the same extension (let's say 2 landlords) could have different permissions. That's exactly what I wanted to avoid, but maybe it's not possible. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Technically, yes, you still don't have any db-level enforcement of your rules (unless you add some trigger in the db of course) - but I've been using this solution in a project without any problem so far (seven years in production now).